# Create a class identified by variables

Tags: ios, class, sprite-kit

*I've always had issues with classes, and I'm not sure if this is possible.*

I'm trying to create a class with an identifiable name.
I realize that that isn't clear, but my overall goal is to create a grid-like game and each square in the grid would be a member in the class.

So for example, I would have a class called square and say in my code

> square(16,47).isdead = true;

Basically, I want to know if it is possible to create a class where I can differentiate between at least a hundred different squares.

*Also, not sure if this matters, but I am using sprite kit*.

Comment: That doesn't sound like separate classes, just separate instances of a single class, with the instances organized in a multidimensional array.

Comment: or organized in a dictionary where the key encodes the grid position, ie "16,47" as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways to do what you want, I would prefer the below method.

C style two dimensional array:

```
Square * squares[10][10];
```

And you encapsulate that in a class called SquareManager with a method:

```
-(Square*) aSquareManager squareX:(short)x Y:(short)y;
```

If you specifically want the access pattern described in your question you can use (credit goes to [arturgrigor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435040/arturgrigor)):

```
#define square(x, y) [aSquareManager squareX:x Y:y]
```

Then you can access all of your squares this way:

```
if ([aSquareManager squareX:16 Y:47].isdead==true) [self showSkullForSquare:[aSquareManager squareX:16 Y:47]];
```

**A different approach would be that a square has x and y properties:**

```
Square.h
@property short y;
@property short x;
```

And then you put them all into an array, and when you need a square you search through the array.

```
for(Square * aSquare in squares) {
   if(aSquare.x==anXValue && aSquare.y==anYValue) {
      return aSquare;
   }
}
```

Functions like these are much quicker than you think.

Comment: And maybe you should write a Macro for him like #define square(x, y) [aSquareManager squareX:x Y:y] so that he can access it like this square(16, 47).isDead